# Error while running react-native run-ios

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, native

I am getting this Exception when running react-native run-ios. While running android version, everything is alright.

Some ideas how to solve this error?

[image]

Comment: This is something related to your app dependencies, some of them not working properly on iOS (some which relates to networking). Are you able to list your dependencies?

Comment: Yes, here they are: https://imgur.com/a/K0VfYJC Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is something related to React Native version and iOS device (maybe iPhone X)

- https://forums.expo.io/t/solved-strange-d-addnetworkinghandler-failure-on-launch/11357
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15762#issuecomment-404096536

So I guess you could try different versions of react native (others 55.x or event 54)

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem myself but react native upgrade was also a part of solution. Problem was also with react native filesystem.